# Why does the C++11 random generator use reference or non-reference parameter has different list?

Tags: c++, random, reference

**Can anyone explain why the function `foo1` returns the same value?**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<random>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;

int foo(default_random_engine& random, uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int>& dis1){
    return dis1(random);
}

int foo1(default_random_engine random, uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int> dis1){
    return dis1(random);
}

int main()
{
    default_random_engine engine(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int> randomInt(1, 10);

    cout << "Way1:\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        cout<<foo(engine, randomInt)<<' ';
    cout<<endl;
    cout << "Way2:\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        cout<<foo1(engine, randomInt)<<' ';
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

> Way1:
> 9 2 5 5 7 7 9 9 6 6
> Way2:
> 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foo1()` takes its parameters **by value**, so *copies* of them are made each time `foo1()` is called.  It generates the same number on every call because it is using the same generator state (ie, the same seed) every time, any updates made to the *copies* are not reflected back to the caller's original objects.

That is not the case with `foo()`, which takes its parameters **by reference**, thus the caller's objects being referred to can be updated by `foo()`.

Comment: Do you mean that the object `randomInt` accesses the same number of the random list produced by the `default_random_engine` in the `foo1`?

Comment: generating a random number causes the state inside a PRNG to be modified so that a different number can be returned next time.  `foo1` always works with a copy of the generator, so you're implicitly saying you want to discard this modified state each time and reset back to the seed value.  e.g. try seeding the generator with a constant and the first value printed from `foo` should be same as every value from `foo1`